# Delete user authenticated Firebase angular 5

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I would like to delete users authenticated by yours KEY, knowing that I am a administrator, firts I created an authservice and after an userService to associate with registered user

[image]

Now in Database I have the associate user
[image]

Now in my code I have
Firts, I created method auth to create user in auth.service.ts

```
    createUser(user: any, path: string) {
    return this.afu.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
                                .then(() => {
                                  return this.service.save(user, path);
                                })
                                .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }
```

this method create user authenticated and create in Database a user, calling the method save

```
    save(user: any, path: string) {
    const createdAt = new Date();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.list(this.PATH + path)
            // .push(user)
              // console.log(createdAt)
            .push({ name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role_id, status: user.status, created_at: createdAt  })
            .then(() => resolve())
    })
  }
```

So, I have to delete this two registers by KEY in my method

```
    remove(key: string, path: string) {
    return this.db.list(this.PATH + path).remove(key);
  }
```

Remebering, I'm administrator

Comment: Could you give more details on the `remove()` function? You call it on `list()`?

Comment: So, this function remove() delete only the data of Database but don't delete of Authentication, I would like to delete both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment I understand you want to "delete the user from Authentication". Use the delete() method of User, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

You get the current user with the `currentUser()` method of the Auth service interface, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentUser

In "pure"  JavaScript you can do the following and user with mail user@mail.com will be deleted from the Authentication list.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("user@mail.com", "abcd")
    .then(function (info) {
       var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
       user.delete();
    });
```

Comment: I done my friend thank you very much perfect, now its work to me, I did so  remove(user: any, path: string) {
    return this.db.list(this.PATH + path).remove(user.key)
                  .then(() => {
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
                      .then(function (info) {
                         var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                         user.delete();
                      });
                  });
  }